# Can not enter subscript via console (lost before System.in)

Tags: java, io, console, java.util.scanner, subscript

### Problem

In short, if you try out the following snippet:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String text = scanner.nextLine(); // enter ₂

System.out.println(text); // 2, not ₂
```

and **enter a subscript number**, like `₂`, `text` is actually `2`, **without subscript**.

#### Tests

Now, I tried to factor out some classic reasons here.

##### Printing?

You can also compare the string instead of printing it, and it is still incorrect:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String text = scanner.nextLine(); // enter ₂

System.out.println(text.equals("₂")); // false
System.out.println(text.equals("2")); // true
```

##### Scanner?

Scanner is capable of doing it correctly, for example if the input is given as `String`:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("₂");
String text = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println(text); // now prints ₂
```

##### System.in?

The issue is still present if factoring out `Scanner` completely, for example:

```java
byte[] data = System.in.readAllBytes(); // enter ₂
String text = new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8).trim();

System.out.println(text);  // 2, not ₂
```

##### Encoding?

It does not seem to be a general problem with Unicode/encoding. When entering another character, such as , it works as expected.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String text = scanner.nextLine(); // enter 

System.out.println(text); //
```

### Hypothesis

It seems that the subscript is lost between the console input and `System.in`, possibly even before reaching Java at all.

Maybe this is a console specific quirk I am not aware of? I tried it with VSC and Windows CMD (Java 18).

Comment: FWIW, the code snippet works OK for me with JDK 18 on Mac OS.

Comment: Good to know. Then its probably an issue with the specific console being used, I suppose.